# Pygame window not opening until all processes are complete macOS 12.2

Tags: python, macos, pygame

macOS Monterey 12.2 M1 Pro

Version: pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.7)

Pygame will not display a window until all my code has run and the program is waiting for input to exit. Once program is complete, Pygame window shows. If I didn't use the following code:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

then the window wouldn't even display at all.

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling pygame. Tried installing older version of pygame (which doesn't work, keep getting errors). Tried installing most recent development version. (2.1.3.dev8)

Having to transfer files to old windows laptop to check if program even works properly. Any ideas why this is happening? Is there an older dev version of pygame that will work instead?

example:

```
import pygame

w_in_squares = 8
h_in_squares = 8

square_dim = 50

drawing_window = pygame.display.set_mode((w_in_squares*square_dim, h_in_squares*square_dim))

drawing_window.fill((127, 127, 127))

the_colour_white = (255, 255, 255)
the_colour_black = (  0,   0,   0)

current_colour = the_colour_white

for i in range(0, h_in_squares):
    for j in range(0, w_in_squares):
        pygame.draw.rect(drawing_window, current_colour, (i * square_dim, j * square_dim, square_dim, square_dim))
        pygame.display.update() 
        pygame.time.delay(100)
        if current_colour == the_colour_white:
            current_colour = the_colour_black
        else:
            current_colour = the_colour_white
    if current_colour == the_colour_white:
        current_colour = the_colour_black
    else:
        current_colour = the_colour_white
        
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

The point of this program is that you are supposed to be able to watch each square of a checkerboard being drawn one by one. Though, only after every square is drawn does the window display.

Comment: Please share a [mre]. There's not really enough info here to see why this is happening.

Comment: I've shared an old example program. Though, this isn't a problem with just a single program. @RandomDavis

Comment: The obvious problem with the example you posted is that your event loop only happens after you do a bunch of drawing and other things that take a while. It's only by explicitly checking the event loop very regularly (once per frame ideally) that you can avoid the window freezing; which is a result of not checking the event loop. You should look at other people's pygame programs and you'll see that you're clearly not checking the event loop nearly enough. See how other people do it and you'll realize your mistake. Maybe take a basic tutorial though if you didn't know this.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but this same program will run on another computer as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on your entire code, but try adding a `pygame.display.update()` in your while loop, this should make pygame keep the screen refreshed.
Again this could not solve your solution because you do not show your full program.